# Maximal subgroups of $G=Z_{3}\ltimes Q_{8}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=Z_{3}\ltimes Q_{8}$. How can find Maximal subgroups of $G$ ?        $$Q_{8}$$ is Quaternion group of order of 8 and $$Z_{3}$$ is cyclic group of order 3

Comment: Well, what do you know about the structure of $Q_8$?  Do you know the definition of a maximal subgroup?

Comment: **Hint:** Use the fact that illustrated by Marshal [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/196041/8581) to see that $$G\cong SL(2,\mathbb Z_3)$$. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Babak: I don't really see how it helps theoretically, but it does make it easier to do it in GAP: you can just type M:=MaximalSubgroups(SL(2,3));